# Google Apps Script and parser: easy way to build a 2d array from two 1d arrays?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using [Parser](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html) to build some arrays from data on a website (and the [cUseful cache service](https://github.com/brucemcpherson/cUseful) to keep from having to read the page every time I want to run the program):

```
function readCrew() {
  var categoryCrewURL = "https://stt.wiki/wiki/Category:Crew"
  var categoryCrewText = "Category-Crew-List";
  var wholePagefromText = 'next page';
  var wholePagetoText = 'previous page';

  var content = getCacheData(categoryCrewURL, categoryCrewText);
  var scraped = Parser
                .data(content)
                .from(wholePagefromText)
                .to(wholePagetoText)
                .build();

  var fromText = 'href="';
  var toText = '"';
  var crewURLs = Parser
                 .data(scraped)
                 .from(fromText)
                 .to(toText)
                 .iterate();
  Logger.log(crewURLs);
  var fromText = 'title="';
  var toText = '">';
  var crewNames = Parser
                  .data(scraped)
                  .from(fromText)
                  .to(toText)
                  .iterate();
  Logger.log(crewNames);
  ssActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  rgMyRange = ssActive.getRange("A:A");
  rgMyRange.setValues(crewNames);
}

function getCacheData(targetURL, targetCacheName) {
  const crusher = new cUseful.CrusherPluginCacheService().init ({
    store:CacheService.getUserCache()
  });
  Logger.log(targetURL);
  Logger.log(targetCacheName);
  var cached = crusher.get (targetCacheName);
  if (cached != null) {
    return cached;
  }
  // This fetch takes 20 seconds:
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(targetURL);
  var contents = result.getContentText();
  crusher.put (targetCacheName, contents);
  return contents;
}
```

the line "rgMyRange.setValues(crewNames);" doesn't work because I only have a 1-dimensional array.  But I ultimately want to write crewNames to column A and crewURLs to column B, which I *think* I could do using a 2d array fairly easily.  Trying to avoid building a loop to iterate across my data if I can.  Is there an easy way (without building such a loop) to combine those two 1d arrays into a 2d array, or something I'm missing in parser that might do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your script, `crewNames` and `crewURLs` are 1 dimensional array.
- You want to put `crewNames` and `crewURLs` to the column "A" and "B" of the active sheet, respectively.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
ssActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
rgMyRange = ssActive.getRange("A:A");
rgMyRange.setValues(crewNames);
```

#### To:

```
var values = crewNames.map(function(e, i) {return [e, crewURLs[i]]}); // Added
ssActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Modified
rgMyRange = ssActive.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length); // Modified
rgMyRange.setValues(values); // Modified
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.